# Recover files from previous OS after Ubuntu installation

Tags: 20.04, backup, mint

So I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a machine that was running Mint LMDE 4. After doing it, I realized I forgot to backup a folder that was in the Documents folder in the Mint OS.

Is that a way to try to recover this folder?

Comment: If you re-partitioned and re-formatted the **same** disk drive, you are (almost) out of luck.

Comment: If the drive is an SSD, you’re *almost certainly* out of luck 

Comment: @matigo it is a Disk hard drive. And yes Ubuntu was installed on top of the formatting of the same disk

Comment: With ext4 data is randomly written onto drive. What % of drive is now used? How much effort are you willing to spend to only get some data back? On a smaller HDD, it took overnight to run photorec & copy data to another drive. I only lost a folder with text files and did have an older backup. As I wrote text files regularly, photorec found multiple copies, lots of work to compare similar files & try to rebuild most current version. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/After_Using_PhotoRec